FFmpeg wasm converting video on any mobile device on any browser
I am still very new at this so my apologies. Thanks for the help!
Converting a video file on mobile returns a mp4 file, however is only 48 bytes in size. The conversion works fine on any desktop browser.
Things to know about this function and or my program in general to help explain all the steps to try and find a solution.


I’m using vue3.js with pinia as state management. Pinia here only gets and displays the current file conversion progress. I’m also trying to make thing a SPA so it is done in the browser in JavaScript.




That the “videos” Param is an array of raw videos files. I saw raw because I have check that they are indeed video file typed and that there is no ref incasing them.




The video is: 53MB, 4K, .MOV, and 6sec long (yes I have test with other video files, this was just the main one) and the return output size was 48 bytes, yeah bytes, big problem for displaying videos later.




Shortly after conversion it is submitted to my database (firebase)




The function in other file is being called with an await
ex: await convertVideosToMP4(vids)
Where vids is a array of video files non-ref



// mixin for video conversion
import { FFmpeg } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';
import { fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/util';
import { useStuntStore } from './stores/stuntStore';

//function to convert videos to MP4
async function convertVideosToMP4(videos) {

    const stuntStore = useStuntStore()
    stuntStore.setUploadStatus("START")

    // Initialize FFmpeg
    const ffmpeg = new FFmpeg({ log: true });
    await ffmpeg.load();

    // Array to store converted videos
    const convertedVideos = [];
    let currentFileNumber = 0;

    ffmpeg.on("progress", ({ progress, time}) => {
        console.log("PROGRESS:", progress, "\nTIME:", time)
        stuntStore.setProgress(Math.trunc(progress * 100));
        console.log(stuntStore.uploadProgress)
    })

    //loop through the array of videos
    stuntStore.setUploadStatus("CONVERTING...")
    for (const video of videos) {
        currentFileNumber++
        stuntStore.setUploadFileCount(currentFileNumber + " of " + videos.length)
        try {
            // Fetch the video file
            const fileData = await fetchFile(video);
            
            // Write the video file to FFmpeg
            await ffmpeg.writeFile('input', fileData);
            
            

            // convert the video to MP4
            await ffmpeg.exec(['-i', 'input', 'output.mp4']);
            
            // Read the converted file
            const data = await ffmpeg.readFile('output.mp4');
            
            const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'video/mp4'})
            const convertedFile = new File([blob], `${video.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '.mp4')}`, { type: 'video/mp4' })
            // Push the converted video data to the array
            convertedVideos.push(convertedFile);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error converting ${video} to MP4:`, error);
            return null
        }
        
    }

    stuntStore.setUploadStatus("CONVERSION DONE")
    // Return the array of converted videos
    return convertedVideos;
}



